# React useEffect refresh does not get value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hej everybody

I am trying to get a hold of the hooks and useEffect but I cannot understand something. My code is this:

```
function RedigeraProdukter() {


    //fetches redux
    const products = useSelector(state => state.products)


    //set local states
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(
        queryString.parse(window.location.search).prod
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        setProduct(queryString.parse(window.location.search).prod);
    }, [queryString.parse(window.location.search).prod]);
```

supposedly when the user gets the link to this page, a prop is passed as query-string which is assign to product. I used the useEffect hook for this effect, however, if I refresh the page, the useEffect does not read the prop and product becomes undefined.

Any solution for this???

Comment: What happens if your useEffect dependency array is `[product]` ?

Comment: get's undefined on the refresh page

Answer (score 3):

The dependency in `useEffect` should be `product` and not `queryString.parse(window.location.search).prod` .

```
function RedigeraProdukter() {

    //fetches redux
    const products = useSelector(state => state.products)

    //set local states
    const [product, setProduct] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        setProduct(queryString.parse(window.location.search).prod);
    }, [product]);

}
```

Comment: does not work at all. This way product is always undefined.

Comment: Is the value of the product getting updated the first time?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `window.location`?

Comment: window.location in the link says to do Link to={'/producter/?k=' + a1} where a1 is gonna be a variable query string. When the user clicks on the link to go the page it works just perfect. The problem is when refreshing, that it does not read this query-string or sets it to the value of product

Comment: @OblicionA Are you using react router?

Comment: yes, but on this case, I have a single "product" page that renders according the query-string, that is why I am passing via query

Comment: Can you put a `console.log("something")` inside useEffect and check if displayed after page refresh?

Comment: I placed and it does not even log anything to the console. It only logs that the first variable that is dependent of [product] is undefined

Comment: After page refresh, are you getting undefined in console or no output in console at all?

Comment: I believe that your problem lies much deeper and not in the code snippet that you have shared in your question.

Comment: yeah I just solved it, the problem was that the reducer (products) had initial state undefined, that is why it was giving problems

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        setProduct(queryString.parse(window.location.search).prod);
    }, [window.location.search]); <-- changed
```

Comment: I understand the thought but does not work either. When landing on the page for the first time it reads, but on the refresh gets undefined.